# PHP Can an injected object access properties of the object it was injected into?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

**Does an injected object have any way to read it's parent's properties?**

Here is an example:

This is a `field` object that holds the name and value of a field, and allows you to inject validation rules:

```php
class field
{
    public string $name;
    public $value;
    public array $validators;
    
    public function __construct($name, $value = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    
    public function addValidator(validatorInterface $validator): field
    {
        $this->validators[] = $validator;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function validate()
    {
        foreach ($this->validators as $validator) {
            if (! $validator->validate()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here are a couple validators:

```php
interface validatorInterface
{
    public function validate(): bool;
}


class stringValidator implements validatorInterface
{
    public function validate(): bool
    {
        return is_string($this->value);
    }
}

class lengthValidator implements validatorInterface
{
    public function validate(): bool
    {
        return strlen($this->value) > 3;
    }
}
```

Now let's take a test run:

```php
$name = new field('name', 'Robert');
$name->addValidator(new stringValidator);
$name->addValidator(new lengthValidator);

echo $name->validate() ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
```

Obviously it fails because the validators have no idea what the `field` object's `$value` property is.

What comes to mind first is to create a setter in each validator that is used by the `field` object to pass the value to each validator:

```php
class field
{
    [...]

    public function addValidator(validatorInterface $validator): field
    {
        $this->validators[] = $validator;
        $validator->setValue($this->value);                 // <--- new line
        return $this;
    }

    [...]

}

class stringValidator implements validatorInterface
{
    private $value;
    
    public function setValue($value): validatorInterface    // <--- new method
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function validate(): bool
    {
        return is_string($this->value);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that now I need to loop through every validator to inform them of the new field value any time it changes, which means that both the `field` instance and the `validatorInterface` instances are both holding a `value` that *should be* in sync, but may not be because they're not actually the same variable.

**Is there any direct way to have the injected validators "just know" what the `field` instance's `value` property is?**

Comment: No, there's no way to do that automatically. Object references only go one way. And an object can be injected in multiple places, which one would you refer back to?

Comment: If you need to do that, you should add a property to the validator that contains the field, and pass the field to the validator constructor.

Comment: So inject the field into the validator which was injected into the field?

Comment: Yes, it's not uncommon to have cross-references like this.

Comment: That is the non-intuitive piece that I was missing. You've made me rethink my whole strategy; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `field` *object* to the validator instead of the *property value* because objects are always passed by reference:

```
class field
{
    [...]

    public function addValidator(validatorInterface $validator): field
    {
        $this->validators[] = $validator->setField($this);
        return $this;
    }

    [...]

}

class stringValidator implements validatorInterface
{
    private $field;
    
    public function setField($field): validatorInterface
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function validate(): bool
    {
        return is_string($this->field->value);
    }
}
```

than you can use it just like your example :

```
$name = new field('name', 'Robert');
$name->addValidator(new stringValidator);
$name->addValidator(new lengthValidator);

echo $name->validate() ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
```

You *could* pass the `field` object in the constructor of the validator but you would need to pass it each time you add a new validator, e.g.: `$name->addValidator(new stringValidator($name));` but the above solution is better.